# "Строим для вас 10 лет"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Не так давно подсмотрела в городе такую вывеску: "Строим для вас 10 лет". Поскольку я коллекционирую всяческие маразмы и ляпы, то сфотографировала ее. Но, когда выложила на одно из тематических сообществ, меня спросили: "А что тут такого? Обычный рекламный слоган". Я пояснила, что, мол, кому охота, чтобы его дом строили 10 лет. Но меня, похоже, так и не поняли.
Так вот, кто прав? Грамотно ли построена фраза и, если нет, то как надо?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы тоже споткнулась об эту фразу, она двусмысленная. Вообще, редко увидишь рекламу без ошибки. Например, такая: "Элитная мебель из Китая! Дешевле, чем в Китае!" Представляете себе "элитную мебель"? Расходы на перевозку, таможенные пошлины и т.д. - и дешевле, чем в Китае. Я верю, что мебель  может быть дешевле.  Но тогда она вряд ли элитная. И смотреть такую мебель не пойду. Вот если бы вместо слова "элитная" написали "качественная"... Или: "Частная клиника по лечению женских заболеваний: ..., простатит, ..."))) Эту рекламу дословно не помню, года два назад во Владивостоке видела, но простатит в ней значился среди женских болезней.

Кстати, многие действительно не замечают ошибок, и даже когда растолковываешь - не сразу понимают.

Answer (score 3):

Фразу действительно можно прочитать двояко. Мне кажется, здесь многое зависит от окружающего "пейзажа". Такой слоган на новой удачной постройке наведет на мысль о качестве и надежности строительной компании. А если баннер висит на доме, который "заморожен" или вялыми темпами строится и рядом группа пикетчиков, то точно появляется уже второе прочтение.

P.S. Просто о вывесках... Была как-то в одной парикмахерской. Там на выходе висела табличка: "Волосы не зубы, отрастут". Табличу дополняла улыбающаяся беззубым ртом баба Яга - мечта дантиста.

Comment: )))))))))))))))))))) Гениально!!)))))) А фотографии этого шедевра нет?))))

Comment: К сожалению, нет :(

Answer (score 2):

Да, я бы тоже  в первую очередь обратила внимание на то, что речь идёт о долгосторое, а потом уже на то, что фирма работает в течение 10 лет.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему,всё нормально. Строить можно конкретно что-то, а можно строить вообще, т.е. заниматься строительством, имеется в виду строим для вас дома, коттеджи,что-то ещё, т. е. занимаемся этим делом 10 лет.

Answer (score 1):

Пока не написали, фразу с долгостроем не связывал. Может потому, что уже привык к подобного рода афонаризмам.

Comment: Вообще, по-моему, этот перл — тест на чувство юмора))) Я просто такие вещи замечаю всегда, это уже привычка — у нас в семье было принято собирать такие вещи. Папа с 1968 года коллекционировал вырезки из "Крокодила" из рубрики "Нарочно не придумаешь".  
И всем огромное спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Возможно, но кого на это чувство тестируют? Читающего или рекламщиков?